# Error CS0053: Inconsistent Accessibility for DbSet Property in .NET Core Entity Framework - How to Resolve?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this simple .net core class library project and trying code first approach for CRUD.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using EFDemoApp_Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFDemoApp_Domain.DataAccess
{
    public class EFDemoAppDataContext:DbContext
    {
        public EFDemoAppDataContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("");
        }
    }
}
```

In the statement `public DbSet<Patient> Patients` the property name `Patients` is showing as the below error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0053  Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'DbSet' is less accessible than property 'EFDemoAppDataContext.Patients'

I am not finding anywhere why this error is showing.

Comment: Show us your Patient model. Odds are good you forgot to make it public.

Comment: @gilliduck thanks,  it was missing.

Comment: Added an answer with a reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing it, I'm assuming your `Patient` model is missing it's public accessor tag. As a reminder, if it's not specified then the default is `internal`.

Comment: @gilliduck I can see that you do not insult anybody else, please allow me to recommend a highler level of language anyway, even towards yourself. You seem to have earned it.

Comment: @gilliduck Also, your ping to the author of the helpful comment seems broken. If you want them to notice you probably have to try again.